# Is "entity component system" a principle or a pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, entity-component

Since the ECS follows the principle *Composition over Inheritance*, and it  makes the behavior of game objects can be changed in the runtime.

If ECS is a principle, from my memory of design patterns of GoF, the following patterns can accomplish the principle well:

1. Decorator pattern
2. Composite + Visitor

But I'm not sure about that ECS is a pattern like the above or a principle like Open Closed Principle, I've tried to find a video which explains ECS well but found nothing clear.

Current resources I found:

- [gamedev.net ECS](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013)

Comment: I don't think it matters to the answers but I'd challenge your assertion that "the goal" of an ECS is runtime modification of components; were you to adopt that, many things that people describe as ECSs would suddenly not be, simply because they chose not to support runtime modification as an optimization. Being able to change objects _easily_ is desirable, but not necessarily at _runtime_.

Comment: One of the issues with defining an entity component system is that there are many different approaches taken when implementing them, so they tend to vary far more than most other patterns.

Comment: I would say that it is one of *pattern*s that *implements the principle* of "Composition over Inheritance".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I had to, I'd say ECS is probably a pattern. Principles are more generic, addressing multiple problem domains. Patterns tend to be more about establishing a shared vocabulary for sets of mostly-similar techniques.

The term "ECS" is used to refer to a technique of creating more-complex game objects (the "entities") out of smaller, less-complex-but-feature-complete objects (the "components"). It is fundamentally a narrowing in scope of the more general principle of preferring composition (as you noted), and I think that makes it sufficient narrow to describe it as a pattern, if you really wanted to get picky about it.

There are still plenty of different ways to actually *write* that code (just as there are many ways to *write* a visitor, or observer, or whatever other Gang of Four pattern strikes your fancy), most of which are perfectly correct. None of it is set in stone and none of it should be. This is probably why you're having a hard time finding a video describing it, because it's complex and there is no single accepted way to do it. Patterns are for assigning names to broad, complex behavior so we can talk about them more easily.

Yes, some patterns are similar and some combinations of patterns can be used to effective achieve the same results as other patterns, as you noticed. That's fine; they aren't supposed to all be orthogonal to eachother.